# Starting Sub SpringBootApplication in Spring project for micro service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to run another spring boot service from existing application, in order and use the same database layer.
The two app should be deferent services with deferent ports.

My project structure is this:

```
 - com.name (Project A)
| - Application
| - com.name.controller
 - com.name.controller2 (New) (Project B)
| - Application2 (New)
| - com.name.controller2.controller (New RestController)
|
 - com.name.storage (Project C)
|
|
 - com.name.service
```

For Application: (It starting with all the controllers endpoints)

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class Application {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

For Application2 I've tryied that with no luck:

```
//@SpringBootApplication(
//      scanBasePackages={"com.name"})
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.name"})
public class Application2{
    SpringApplication.run(Application2.class, args);
}
```

I've tried many variations but couldn't get it right.
If I'm using "com.name.storage" as basePackages the app is starting with no configuration at all (not recognizing the rest endpoints of it's controller), but listening to the new port.

Can you help me with the right configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SpringApplicationBuilder uws = new SpringApplicationBuilder(UserWebApplication.class)
        .properties("server.port=8081",
                    "server.contextPath=/UserService");
uws.run();
SpringApplicationBuilder pws = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ProjectWebApplication.class)
        .properties("server.port=8082",
                    "server.contextPath=/ProjectService");
pws.run();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, why not to use SpringApplication.run(Application2.class, args)?

Comment: You can definitely use your one application. I posted a code snippet from my project

Comment: I think I wasn't clear with the problem.
The apps are separate projects. this link describes the problem and the solution:
http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-component-scan
But for some reason, Project C components are not found for the Autowire fields of Project B.
I've changed Project A package to com.name.controller1 so it won't be in the same package tree as Project C and got the same problem.
Beans of project C could not found for Project A.